# "apt-get dist-upgrade" shows kept-back package

Tags: apt

As far as I know, *kept back* packages in Debian are shown in case package can not be upgraded with `apt-get upgrade` because upgrade requires to install new packages. Usually this can be fixed with `apt-get dist-upgrade` because this will install new packages if needed.

Now for some reason `db5.1-util` package is kept back despite the fact that I execute `apt-get dist-upgrade`:

```
root@server:~# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  db5.1-util
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
root@server:~#
```

I even don't need the `db5.1-util` package because it satisfies dependencies for packages(`partimage-server` and `db-upgrade-util`) which I don't have installed:

```
root@server:~# apt-cache rdepends db5.1-util
db5.1-util
Reverse Depends:
  partimage-server
  db-upgrade-util
root@server:~# apt-cache policy db5.1-util partimage-server db-upgrade-util
db5.1-util:
  Installed: 5.1.29-5
  Candidate: 5.1.29-9
  Version table:
     5.1.29-9 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stable/main i386 Packages
 *** 5.1.29-5 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
partimage-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.6.8-3
  Version table:
     0.6.8-3 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stable/main i386 Packages
db-upgrade-util:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.3.0
  Version table:
     5.3.0 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stable/main i386 Packages
root@server:~#
```

Am I correct that `db5.1-util` is kept back because it replaces `libdb5.1` which is required by `python2.6` which I have installed? Output of `apt-cache` can be seen below:

```
root@server:~# apt-cache depends db5.1-util
db5.1-util
  Depends: libc6
  Breaks: libdb5.1
  Replaces: libdb5.1
root@server:~# apt-cache rdepends libdb5.1
libdb5.1
Reverse Depends:
  python2.6
  db5.1-util
  db5.1-util
  db5.1-util
root@server:~# apt-cache policy python2.6
python2.6:
  Installed: 2.6.8-1.1
  Candidate: 2.6.8-1.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.6.8-1.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
root@server:~#
```

// output of `apt-cache policy db5.1-util libdb5.1 libc6` can be seen below:

```
root@server:~# apt-cache policy db5.1-util libdb5.1 libc6
db5.1-util:
  Installed: 5.1.29-5
  Candidate: 5.1.29-9
  Version table:
     5.1.29-9 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stable/main i386 Packages
 *** 5.1.29-5 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libdb5.1:
  Installed: 5.1.29-5
  Candidate: 5.1.29-5
  Version table:
 *** 5.1.29-5 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libc6:
  Installed: 2.19-18
  Candidate: 2.19-18
  Version table:
 *** 2.19-18 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stable/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
root@server:~#
```

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy db5.1-util partimage-server db-upgrade-util`?

Comment: @Braiam I improved my initial question.

Comment: I didn't notice this but you added the reverse dependencies, instead of the dependencies, add the output of `apt-cache depends db5.1-util` instead.

Comment: @Braiam Added. I also once again improved the initial question.

Comment: Ok, now replace the output of `apt-cache policy db5.1-util partimage-server db-upgrade-util` that you added first, with the output of `apt-cache policy db5.1-util libdb5.1 libc6`.

Comment: @Braiam Output of `apt-cache policy db5.1-util libdb5.1 libc6` added.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem while doing a Jessie `apt upgrade` (in preparation for a dist-upgrade).

The solution was to simply

```
apt-get remove db5.1-util
```